# Dirt 2: Any way to avoid all the startup splash screens?

Tags: pc, dirt-2

Dirt 2 must have the most startup splash screens I've ever seen in a PC game.

Sometimes I avoid firing it up because of how long it takes to load up. Is there any way to just jump right into the action and avoid all the startup splash and jazz?

Answer (score 4):

For most of the videos, you can just press 'Enter' to skip them. The downside is that you will have to press it several times.

You can also replace some of the videos with blank files. There is some detailed info on this in a [post on the Codemasters forum](http://community.codemasters.com/forum/dirt-2-game-pc-1313/409084-how-skip-intros-save-games-config-offline.html).

To summarize, the video files are located in the `<DiRT 2 installation folder>\video` directory. If you bought the game through Steam, it will be something like `D:\Steam\SteamApps\common\dirt 2\video`, where `D:\Steam` is the Steam installation.

The replaceable files are `AMD_sting.bik`, `ego_sting.bik`, and `sting.bik`/`sting_us.bik`. The first two you can just rename or replace with 0-length files. The last two reportedly cause the game to sometimes freeze if treated the same way, so they can be replaced with a short (1-second or so) video instead.

Comment: Can I just rename .avi or other video file types to sting.bik / sting_us.bik?

Comment: @David I think it's a different format, but you can create a .bik from .avi with a program like [Rad Tools](http://www.radgametools.com/bnkdown.htm). Instructions are in [this reply](http://community.codemasters.com/forum/dirt-2-game-pc-1313/409084-how-skip-intros-save-games-config-offline.html#post6075836) to the Codemasters forum post I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

use the startup flag `-novid` to skip the first couple .biks
Thanks [Kiarash](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=19975277&postcount=8)